# Transition Graph per alphabet?

Tags: graph, finite-automata, computation-theory, automata-theory

How do you determine how many different Transition Graphs are over a particular alphabet? For example How many TG's are over the alphabet {x, y}. I am taking a class with a similar question from Daniel I. A. Cohen's book, "Introduction to computer theory." There are plenty of examples of how to create a TG but nothing to determine how many can be created per language. I'm assuming I'm looking for finite amount of TG's? Thank You very much!

Comment: You should ask this on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that even existed, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are countably infinitely many such transition graphs.  One way to think about this is that you can easily construct a family of infinitely many transition graphs as follows.  Suppose that I want to accept the language a<sup>n</sup> for some fixed n (that is, n copies of the letter a).  Then I could construct a transition graph that accepts that language as follows.  Begin with a start state, then chain n new states onto the end of that state, each with a transition on 'a' to the next state.  Make the last state accepting.

To see that there are only countably infinitely many of these, we can think of how we would describe these automata.  We could do so by writing out the number of states in unary, then the transisions between those states as a list of tuples (start, end, character) (all encoded in binary), then the accepting states as a list of the numbers of the states in unary.  Concatenated together, this is a binary string, and there are only countably many finite binary strings.

Comment: OK, wonderful. I don't fully understand just yet but you have given me some good key words to research. Thank You.